# Ubuntu does not start after the upgrade / error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `cd0'

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi

A couple of days ago, I launched on my **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** laptop

```
username@username~$> sudo apt upgrade
```

, then minimized the terminal and after a while turned off the laptop, forgetting to check whether the terminal completed the command. The next time I turned on the laptop, as always **grub** met me, I typed

```
grub> exit
```

as always and chose the fourth option in **Boot Manager** (as always) (UEFI Onboard LAN IPv4 (50-9A-4C-B3-C9-0B)).
I expected that, as always, the Unity shell would meet me, I would enter my password and start working. But this did not happen, I got **3 errors**, after which **grub** instantly appeared. I did not even have time to read what kind of errors. I recorded these errors on the camcorder and looked at the pause what errors they were and read them:

```
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `cd0'
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `cd0'
error: no such device: b3e461d6rced4-45a8-afe4-2094d34ae956
```

That is the problem, I cannot start the system.

**UPD.**
What I tried to do to solve the problem:
I don’t understand this, but I saw a tip on the site to make a **bootable USB flash drive**: I made it with Ubuntu 16.04.6 (Downloaded from the official Ubuntu site). I started the laptop with it, chose *Try Ubuntu without installing*, but at the end a black screen was highlighted and nothing happened (I left the laptop for 30 minutes, but nothing changed).
After that, I turned off the laptop and selected *Check disk for defects*. The result showed *Check finished: errors found in 7 files!*.

The other options in Boot Manager is:
*HDD1-ubuntu (TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100)

HDD2-ubuntu (TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100)

UEFI Onboard LAN IPv6 (50-9A-4C-B3-c(-0B)*
First one returning me the same errors as fourth (which I tell about the beginning of this text)
Second one returning me the menu with 4 options:
*Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

System setup

Restore Ubuntu 16.04 to factory state*
If I choose 'Ubuntu', then I have a blinking capslock indicator and about of 20 lines of text, in which the last one is

```
[   0.721315] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on onknown-block(0,0)
```

and after this nothing happened.
Third one returning me the same errors as fourth (which I tell about the beginning of this text).

**UPD.**
I have noticed very strange thing for me: if I put random dvd-disk(some films) in drive, and try to choose the fourth option in Boot Manager(which I regularly choose), there is no 3 errors appears, only one(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjCcq.jpg). I think it is the error on the third line in errors when I tried without dvd-disk.
Another strange thing with the dvd-disk inside the laptop: if I also put a bootable USB flash drive and choose the option *Try Ubuntu without installing* then default(like as after installation) Ubuntu desktop will appear after some time, but I nothing can do on it. Mouse cursor doesn't appear, keyboard do nothing, and time is frozen on 6:00, looks like a look at static picture

Comment: As a guess, it looks like your computer is trying to boot off a disk which does not exist, perhaps a CD.  If you cannot boot a live session though, I can think of no way to help you.

Comment: I ended up having to reinstall the system